# Angular nested and re-used components are not triggering 'routerLink' when clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

Ok, so this has done my head in for days now....

Essentially have an Angular app which is reusing components on certain pages, but when a component is included, clicking on the links within it changes the URL, but nothing happens. No errors are thrown either which makes it impossible to debug.

The components I have are as follows:

- Home
- Featured
- Highlighted
- Detail

The components are nested/re-used like so:

**Home**

- Featured
- Highlighted

Clicking on any of the links in the Featured or Highlighted components then takes the user to the Detail components (this works).

Once on the Detail component, I re-include the Highlighted component again, which essentially then allows the user to navigate to another single Detail record.

The problem is that this second link within the Detail component when included, doesn't trigger anything. The URL changes, but it doesn't navigate to another Detail record.

Contents of the files are as follows:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/videos/home/home.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './components/videos/detail/detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "video/:id",
        children: [
          {
            path: "",
            component: DetailComponent,
            pathMatch: "full"
          },
          {
            path: "video/:id",
            children: [
              {
                path: "",
                component: DetailComponent,
                //pathMatch: "full"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" id="body">

    <section id="featured" class="odd py-5">

      <div class="container">

        <app-featured></app-featured>

        <app-highlighted></app-highlighted>

      </div>
      
    </section>

    <section id="more-to-watch" class="even pt-5">

      <div class="container">

        <h3 class="pt-5 pb-4">More to watch</h3>

        <div class="row pb-5">
          <div *ngFor="let video of videos" class="col-3 mb-5">
            <div class="media-item">
              <a class="image-link" routerLink="/video/{{ video.id }}">
                  <img src="assets/image_fill.png" crossorigin class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                  <span style="background-image: url('http://localhost:1337{{ video?.attributes?.image_file?.data?.attributes?.url }}');"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="item-body pt-3">
                  <div class="item-meta-categories text-uppercase">
                      <span class="badge text-bg-secondary" *ngFor="let category of video.attributes.categories.data">{{ category.attributes.name }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-title pt-3">
                      <h5><a routerLink="/video/{{ video.id }}">{{ video.attributes.title }}</a></h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-meta-stats pt-2">
                      <span>Added 2 days ago</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </section>

</div>
```

**detail.component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" id="body">

    <section class="pt-5">

      <div class="container">

        <vg-player *ngIf="video" [ngClass]="video ? 'loaded' : ''">
          <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
          <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
          <vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
            <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
          </vg-scrub-bar>
          <vg-controls>
            <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
            <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
            <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
            <vg-scrub-bar style="pointer-events: none;"></vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-time-display vgProperty="left" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
            <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
            <vg-track-selector></vg-track-selector>
            <vg-mute></vg-mute>
            <vg-volume></vg-volume>
            <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
          </vg-controls>
          <video #media [vgMedia]="$any(media)" id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin>
            <source src="http://localhost:1337{{ video.data.attributes.video_file.data.attributes.url }}" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </vg-player>

      </div>
      
    </section>

    <section id="more-to-watch" class="even py-5">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h1 class="pt-5 pb-2  ">
              {{ video?.data?.attributes.title }}
            </h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="page-meta text-uppercase pt-2 pb-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <span class="auth-avatar">
                    <img src="http://localhost:1337/uploads/thumbnail_display_pic_414051c7b8.jpg" alt="Me!" />
                  </span>
                  <span class="auth-name">
                    By <a href="#">{{ video?.data?.attributes?.user.data.attributes.firstname + ' ' + video?.data?.attributes?.user.data.attributes.lastname }}</a>
                  </span>
                  <span class="post-date">
                    {{ video?.data?.attributes?.publishedAt | date :'dd MMMM y @ h:mm a' }}
                  </span>
                  <span class="comment-stats"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col post-actions text-end">
                  <a routerLink="#" class="rnd-btn">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faMail"></fa-icon>
                  </a>
                  <a routerLink="#" class="rnd-btn">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faLink"></fa-icon>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <markdown [data]="video?.data?.attributes.content"></markdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h5 class="pt-5 mt-3 text-center">More Information</h5>
            <div class="video-information mt-3 p-4">
              <h6>Format</h6>
              <p>MPEG/4</p>
              <h6>Length</h6>
              <p>122 minutes</p>
              <h6>Subtitles</h6>
              <p>Yes</p>
              <h6 *ngIf="video?.data?.attributes.presenters">Presenters</h6>
              <p>{{ video?.data?.attributes.presenters }}</p>
              <hr>
              <div class="text-center text-uppercase">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Transcript <fa-icon [icon]="faDownload"></fa-icon></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </section>

    <section id="featured" class="odd pt-5">

      <div class="container">

        <app-highlighted></app-highlighted>

      </div>
      
    </section>

</div>
```

**highlighted.component.html**

```
<h3 class="mt-5 pb-4">Editor&rsquo;s Picks</h3>

<div class="row pb-5">
    <div *ngFor="let highlight of highlighted" class="col">
    <div class="media-item">
        <a class="image-link" [routerLink]="['/video', highlight.id]">
            <img src="assets/image_fill.png" crossorigin class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <span style="background-image: url('http://localhost:1337{{ highlight?.attributes?.image_file?.data?.attributes?.url }}');"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="item-body pt-3">
            <div class="item-meta-categories text-uppercase">
                <span class="badge text-bg-secondary" *ngFor="let category of highlight.attributes.categories.data">{{ category.attributes.name }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="item-title pt-3">
                <h5><a routerLink="/video/{{ highlight.id }}">{{ highlight.attributes.title }}</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="item-meta-stats pt-2">
                <span>Added 2 days ago</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe this is all that's needed to identify the issue, but let me know if I've missed any files.

Reconfiguring the routes and trying different combinations.

Used multiple router-outlet tags, which didn't work either.

Comment: If you haven't already, turn on [`withDebugTracing`](https://angular.io/api/router/withDebugTracing). It will give you more information about which routes it is trying to match.